# Script gives error when spreadsheet range doesn't exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this simple line of code in my Google Apps Script:

```
  s.getRange('C2:C').clearContent();
```

but sometimes my spreadsheet only has one row, so C1 is there but C2:C does not exist. In such case, the script gives an error.

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same function as the above code but so that there is no error when only Row 1 exists?

I have this so far, but I don't know if there's anything wrong with it. It seems too simple:

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = s.getRange('C:C');
  var howManyRows = values.getNumRows();

    if (howManyRows >= 2)
       s.getRange('C2:C').clearContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `getMaxRows()` returns the [number of available rows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet?hl=en#getMaxRows) in a sheet, so you could use it in a condition like this :

```
if(s.getMaxRows()>1){s.getRange('C2:C').clearContent()}
```